# Keeping inner div respectful of footer in responsive modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a modal popup which looks like the following:
[image: diagram]

The header and footer are supposed to be 50 pixels tall, the left bar will generally not be a concern. The main, however, can have a lot of variance in how big it is.

I'm trying to make this look responsive on many screens, so I've got the outer container set as max-height: 70%. I'd like the main div to be independently scrollable, such that the header and footer remain in place. I'd like the popup to not use up more space than it needs, and to be viewable on a variety of screens.

I'm not having much luck - keeping .main from expanding downwards and forcing the footer off the popup (and rendering beneath the parent div) without explicitly setting its height is a bit of a nightmare.

I'm using Bootstrap. Below is the CSS and HTML.

Thoughts on how this can be done?

HTML:

```
<div class="expand_element modal fade hide in" style="max-height: 70%; display: block;" aria-hidden="false"><div class="modal-header"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a><h3 style="font-size: initial;">Expanded view</h3></div>
    <div id="outer" style="overflow-x: hidden; position: relative">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="left"><h2>Description</h2></div>
            <div class="main">Main</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div></div></div>
```

Style:

```
.outer { width: 90%; }
.left { width: 100px; float: left; }
.middle { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 42px; }
.main { max-height: 80%; overflow-y: auto; font-size: 10px }
.footer { height: 40px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 4px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 15px }
```

Comment: I'd suggest NOT using modal dialogs for mobile; modal dialogs simply wastes too much space on a limited screen space especially with a layout like yours. Instead you may want to show it as a different page.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is update to the latest Bootstrap, version 3.1.1. It has numerous features for mobile-first responsiveness built in already, and you can customize the download to contain only the components you plan to use, here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize.

An excellent guide to migrating over to 3.x is available here:
http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

The reason I say this is because your code still has the "hide" class along with the "modal" and "fade" classes, and in Bootstrap 3.x this is no longer necessary, so I suspect you're still using the older version.

I happen to be arm-wrestling with a similar issue to yours right now, so when I get it sorted out I'll be glad to return and share my solution. Meanwhile I recommend that upgrade!

Cheers.